# WebStorm thinks React functional component is unused variable

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I am writing a stateless function component in React using WebStorm:

```
// file1.js
import React from "react";
export default function MyComp({foo}) { return <span>{ foo }</span>; }
```

Later, I reference the component:

```
import MyComp from "./file1";
// ... in my other component ...
// I am definitely using the component:
render() { return <MyComp foo="bar"/> }
```

When performing code analysis, WebStorm complains with the following warning:

```
Warning:(6, 25) Unused function MyComp
```

Is this a bug in WebStorm? Do I need to configure WebStorm for React?

Thanks.

Comment: WebStorm understands that a function is a React component only when you have parameter named `props`, e.g. `export default function MyComp(props) { return <span>{props.name}</span>; }`; which seems to be the most common way to define react components.

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara What ablout destruction? `function MyComp({ prop1, prop2 }) { \\... }`

Comment: The latest WebStorm 2016.3 has a different login of detecting React components that handles better the cases like in the example. See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22651 Should you have any issues, please provide a code sample.